# How to make Postfix Receive Email for 2 IPs/Domains on one server?

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I have a dedicated server. I've added a second IP in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Both domains are working. And both `send` emails correctly, displaying their respective domain names. My problem is that domain2 `receives` email in the domain1 user account.

I created two user accounts:

```
netadmin
ceo
```

I created a `Virtual` file in `/etc/postfix/virtual` and added 2 catch-alls:

```
@domain1.com    netadmin
@domain2.com    ceo
```

I added this line at the bottom of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I also changed in that file the `mydestination` line to:

```
mydestination = domain1.com, localhost.domain1.com, localhost, domain2.com
```

I then ran:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
service postfix reload
```

I use `Alpine` for my emails. But I never receive emails I've test sent to the `ceo` user account. All emails go to the `netadmin` user account for domain1.

Is there anything I can do so that domain2 receives its emails?

Comment: Did you ran `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` after making changes?

Comment: @gf_ - I did. I did that after creating the virtual file.